# Vue Application Using Chartkick Doesn't update chart correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts

I know my mount and computed methods work since I can send that out to be displayed, but my graph only renders after I change the data value in the template to the correct thing that one time and doesn't render it again.  Should I be using method so it calculates it everytime or do I need to use Vuex for this issue?  Thanks

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    {{getDates}}
    <v-card class="mt-3 mx-auto" max-width="500">
      <v-sheet
        class="v-sheet--offset mx-auto"
        color="cyan"
        elevation="12"
        min-width="125%"
        max-width="calc(100% - 32px)"
      >
        <line-chart :data="dates"></line-chart>
      </v-sheet>

      <v-card-text class="pt-0">
        <div class="title font-weight-light mb-2">Lead</div>
        <div class="subheading font-weight-light grey--text">TEST TEXT</div>
        <v-divider class="my-2"></v-divider>
        <v-icon class="mr-2" small>mdi-clock</v-icon>
        <span class="caption grey--text font-weight-light">TEST TEXT</span>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
    <p>108J View</p>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "E108J",
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      value: [246, 446, 675, 510, 590, 610, 760],
      datas: [],
      dates: {},
      lead: [],
      datesnlead: {}
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/E108J")
      .then(response => (this.datas = response.data));
  },
  computed: {
    getDates() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++) {
        this.dates[this.datas[i].date] = this.datas[i].lead;
      }
      return this.dates;
    },
    getLead() {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.datas.length; i++) {
        this.lead[i] = this.datas[i].lead;
      }
      return this.lead;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You have described the expected behavior. When this component is mounted you retrieve data from your API and change the `datas` field. After that `getDates` is computed and it will change the `dates` data attribute. After that, it is not going to change anymore.

Comment: @aquilesb This is where I am confused.  getDates should be changing the dates variable, which it is as I can see it displayed at {{dates}} on my screen, but when I use dates as the data for my chart it only updates it correctly when I first change it to dates and save it that one time.  Then when I reload the page it doesn't come back right.

Comment: Reload the page, do you mean F5? Because if you reload the page, the `mounted` event will be fired again, and again you will load the data. The only thing I can see in your code, which I would change, is I would remove `this.dates`, you don't need this variable. You can create a variable internally in `getDates` function and return it after populate with `this.datas` data. And every time you need the dates, you call `getDates`.